# Countdown in C# by using loops

Tags: c#, winforms

count-down isn't working ! can anyone tell me why ?
I want to create a countdown by using **for-loop**, not by using timer or other built-in methods...

```
   int totaltime, time;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        totaltime = int.Parse(label1.Text);
        time = int.Parse(label1.Text);
        for (int i = totaltime; i <= 0; i--)
        {
            --time;
            label1.Text = time.ToString();
            Task.Delay(1000);
        }
```

[to see code and application s.s click here !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg1E7.jpg)

Comment: But you cannot use a simple loop without blocking the UI

Comment: Task.Delay(x) will only return a task but has no further effct here. You can remove it and everything will be the same. You have to await that task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
int totaltime, time;
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    totaltime = int.Parse(label1.Text);
    time = int.Parse(label1.Text);
    for (int i = totaltime; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        --time;
        label1.Text = time.ToString();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific: What are you expecting? What did you get? *Still not working* can be anything

Comment: Oh, I just got another issue in your loop code. Check the edit